# T-Forward measure and tenors

Tags: risk-neutral-measure

As far as I understand, a T-forward measure is associated with a situation when a zero-coupon bond with the same maturity, i.e. $P(t,t+T)$, is used as a numeraire. However, given that the yield curves, LIBOR, used to derive this bods have in the markets maturities only upto $12M$, what do we do when $T > 12M$? In such cases $P(t,t+T)$ is no longer a tradable (or even observable) asset and hence can't be used as a numerarie.

Answer (score 1):

The current LIBORs (say O/N, 1wk, 1m, 2m, 3m, 6m, and 1y) refer to the borrowing cost for borrowing starting today (technically this is the spot date, which differ by currency,e.g. T+1, but we can call it today!). Each of these rates will have its own discounting curve. Let's focus on the 3 months rate.

The current 3 month LIBOR refers to borrowing today for 3 months. To construct the discount curve, as you correctly pointed out, we need the borrowing costs for future periods, so we need additional contracts/intruments. Luckily you have the 3 months FRAs (forward rate agreements) which give you the cost of borrowing for 3 months, starting in the future. You have the future contracts, which are similar to FRAs, but there are some subtle differences between FRAs and futures as you would know. You then have the swaps referencing 3 months LIBORs, and these swaps can go to very long maturities, say 50 years. So you can construct the discount curve for 3 months LIBOR by combining these contracts (e.g.,bootstrapping). You can do the same for the other LIBORs, so each LIBOR (3m, 6m etc) can have its own discount curve.

Normally you would use the longest maturity zero coupon as the nuemraire, but you don't have to. If the nuemraire asset is such that it stays alive over the horizon of your interest, then you are obviously fine. But if not then you can use a hybrid numeriare- e.g., hybrid of zero coupon and bank account.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, isn't the curve constructed in this way, say for 3M LIBOR, tells us what the borrowing rate is for a given maturity, say 10 years, PROVIDED that the interest is payed every 3 months? In this case, we can;t use it to derive zero-coupon bond since that bond does not pay any coupons and only pays at maturity. Thanks

Comment: You normally see only FRA futures and swaps get used in the curve contradiction. Non govies Bonds usually get modelled in the z spread sense ( also they carry idiosyncratic risk), and liquidity is also an issue .

Comment: It seems I wasn't clear enough in what I was trying to convey. To construct a ZC bond with maturity, say, 10Y to  be used as a numeraire, we need a yield curve that gives a borrowing rate for 10 years without any repayments between now and 10 years, but there is no such curve since the longest tenor is 12 months, so a 10-year rate from this curve assumes that there will be 10 payments between now and 10 years. So, how do we get the 10Y-forward measure if there is no 10Y ZC bond?

Comment: Ah I see. There is a simple relationship between the price of the zero coupon and the simple forward rates, please look it up - it comes up a lot. Libor is like simple forward, and you are essentially ‘stringing’ together these instruments so that there is only a payment of 1 at the maturity.

Comment: So, how do we discount a cash flow that tskes place in, say, 13 months when the long LIBOR rate is for 12 months?

Comment: You will use some form of interpolation on the curve that I described earlier

Comment: I'm not following.  Say we have a 12M LIBOR curve for a maturities of 1 year,  2 years, etc. If we use the 1 year and 2 year rates to interpolate, this assumes that there will be a payment at 12 months followed by a payment at 13 months, but we only have 1 payment at 13 months. The available rates assume different frequency of payments than the one we are interested in. You can't just interpolate one frequency to get another, that's  why we don't intepolate say 12M to get 6M. No?

Comment: You would have instruments referencing forwards for a lot of starting dates, e.g., for 12 months LIBOR, you will have the 12 months LIBOR, then say FRAs 1x13, 2x14, etc.

Comment: But they just tell us what the 12M rate is expected to be in 1 month, 2 months etc. None of them tell me what the rate for, say, 18M is now. There is an extra 6 months of credit / liquidity risk in 18M borrowing which is not reflected in any of the above. Simply interpolating between the two 12M rates for 1 and 2 years (where the latter reflects the fact that there is a payment after the first 12 months) does not seem appropriate either. It seems to me what should be done is to model how the risk premium / spread changes with each additional month of borrowing and this then "added" to the 12M.

Comment: So the suggestion is there should be outright rate for 12 months, and then an outright rate for 13 months and so? What would be the lending term of these rates? Different I suppose?

Comment: @confounded what you are describing is how to discount uncollateralized cash flows, where you are exposed to the ability of your counterparty to pay you back in the future.  Most of the derivatives market is actually cllateralized , so that risk free rates are used as discount rates, hence no need for long term credit risk in the calculation

Comment: @dm63 Thank you for your comment, but what about unconsolidated lending in money market or pricing of corporate bonds? Which curve does one use to PV a cash flow in , say, 18 months? Thanks

Comment: You can look for similarly risky corporate bonds of the same maturity and see what discount rate the market is applying.  Alternatively , if you are a credit risk expert , you can study the company in depth and reach your own conclusion as to how risky the cash flows are, relative to other similar entities.